# how to use dropnet, sharpbox and othere libraries in Monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android

I have created on image uploader as a desktop application. Now I want to port it to Android using Monodroid.
Application uploads images to dropbox.  In the desktop version I have used "dropnet" which references "sharpbox", "Json", etc. Is there any way I can use those i.e. dropnet, sharpbox, etc in my monodroid app?

It will take very long if I have to recode those libraries already available in .net .

thanks.
Sujit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DropNet already has a compilation for MonoTouch. So you should be able to create a MonoDroid compilation in the same way - Just create a MonoDroid class library project, add all the files as links and compile.

You could even submit it as a pull request to the DropNet project.

Edit:
I've forked DropNet [here](https://github.com/SpiritMachine/DropNet), and created a MonoDroid compilation.
Just clone this repository.

Disclamer: I just got it to build - it's up to you to address any issues you might come across.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How to add files as Links? I am very new to monodroid development (about a week). 

Below is the path from where I have added Dropnet.dll and RestSharp.MonoTouch.dll . Its giving error when I try to get AccountInfo.

dkarzon-DropNet-5513999\dkarzon-DropNet-5513999\DropNet.MonoTouch\bin\Debug

Thanks.

Comment: You will need the source files, not the compiled binaries.
Clone the Git repository, create a new MonoDroid library project. From the _Add_ menu, choose _Existing Item_. From here you can choose the source files and in the bottom right of the file browser, instead of _Add_, choose _Add as Link_. If you want to know which files to add, copy the MonoTouch project.

Comment: Also RestSharp already has a MonoDroid build. You'll want to use that instead of MonoTouch.